# what happens if I move file into file?

Tags: linux, file, mv

I accidentally did

```
::> mv file1 file2
```

file1 disappeared. Is there a way to get it back ?
Shouldn't move fail such operations ?

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No, this is an intended behavior of `mv`. Alias `mv` to `mv -i` to prevent it in the future.

Comment: If the files are source files, you should use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Well, you renamed file1 to file2. So file1 is there...just renamed to file2. File2 is gone. You can get it back but it is a lot of forensic work - ask in superuser or serverfault communities. You will have to set noclobber or use mv in interactive mode (`mv --interactive ...` or `mv -i` like duskwuff said).